# Two foreign keys on same table: how to implement on delete cascade?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, ddl

I have a table with two columns. Each of them is a foreign key to the same second table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBL_TOGETHER]
(
    [ID1] [int] NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [TBL_ANOTHER_TABLE](ID),
    [ID2] [int] NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [TBL_ANOTHER_TABLE](ID)
)
```

But now I can not delete entities from `TBL_ANOTHER_TABLE` anymore:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK__TBL_ASD__4DE98D56".

My question is: what is the best solution to implement `ON DELETE CASCADE` at `TBL_TOGETHER`?

I tried to add `ON DELETE SET NULL` or `ON DELETE CASCADE` on the foreign key, but it does not work because of cycle or multiple cascade paths.

I have tried to add a delete trigger on `TBL_ANOTEHR_TABLE`, but it still conflicts with the foreign key:

```
ALTER TRIGGER REMOVE_FORENGKEY
ON TBL_ANOTHER_TABLE 
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE TBL_TOGETHER
    SET TBL_TOGETHER.ID1 = NULL
    FROM TBL_TOGETHER
    JOIN deleted ON TBL_TOGETHER.ID1 = deleted.ID;

    UPDATE TBL_TOGETHER
    SET TBL_TOGETHER.ID2 = NULL
    FROM TBL_TOGETHER
    JOIN deleted ON TBL_TOGETHER.ID2 = deleted.ID;
END
```

I have tried an `INSTEAD OF DELETE`-trigger but this approach also doesn't work because the referenced table ALSO contains a foreign key with cascade constraints.

```
ALTER TRIGGER REMOVE_FORENGKEY
ON TBL_ANOTHER_TABLE 
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE TBL_TOGETHER
    SET TBL_TOGETHER.ID1 = NULL
    FROM TBL_TOGETHER
    JOIN deleted ON TBL_TOGETHER.ID1 = deleted.ID;

    UPDATE TBL_TOGETHER
    SET TBL_TOGETHER.ID2 = NULL
    FROM TBL_TOGETHER
    JOIN deleted ON TBL_TOGETHER.ID2 = deleted.ID;

    DELETE TBL_ANOTHER_TABLE 
    FROM TBL_ANOTHER_TABLE 
    JOIN deleted ON TBL_ANOTHER_TABLE.ID = deleted.ID 
    WHERE TBL_ANOTHER_TABLE.ID = deleted.ID;
END
```

Error:

> Cannot alter INSTEAD OF DELETE or INSTEAD OF UPDATE TRIGGER 'REMOVE_FORENGKEY' on table 'TBL_ANOTHER_TABLE '. This is  because the table has a FOREIGN KEY with cascading DELETE or UPDATE.

Comment: SQL Server only supports a single cascade. If having both is important, you'll need to handle this a different way to using `CASCADE`, such as instead of triggers, or forcing users to use SP's to complete deletes, which handles the delete statements gracefully.

Comment: If you want to manage the delete in an instead of trigger you should remove the cascading from the foreign key.

Comment: I do not want to remove the cascading from the referenced TBL_ANOTHER_TABLE, because it shall also automatically be deleted on cascade.

Comment: But you are trying to handle the cascading portion in an instead of trigger. You can't do both. That is what the error message is clearly telling you.

Comment: If you want to use `CASCADE`, then you'll have to chose 1 key to handle the Cascade, and then not allow people to delete rows that'll affect the other "tree"; probably invalidating the point of the Cascade on the key then. If you want to use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger then, like @SeanLange said, you have to use the trigger for everything; you can't mix the 2 solutions. If you *can* control the users, then personally I'd go with the SP route, but otherwise the instead of trigger will be the way to go.

Comment: Ok thank you all... I wrote a procedure which will delete entries from `TBL_TOGETHER` before deleting from referenced `TBL_ANOTEHR_TABLE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this trigger :
this trigger acts instead of delete. therefore you must delete record(s) after set references to null.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_TBL_ANOTHER_TABLE
    ON [dbo].[TBL_ANOTHER_TABLE]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
    AS 
    BEGIN

        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        UPDATE  t
        SET     t.ID1 = NULL
        from [dbo].[TBL_TOGETHER] t inner join
        deleted d on d.ID = t.ID1

        UPDATE  t
        SET     t.ID2 = NULL
        from [dbo].[TBL_TOGETHER] t inner join
        deleted d on d.ID = t.ID2

        DELETE  t
        from [dbo].[TBL_ANOTHER_TABLE] t inner join
        deleted d on d.ID = t.ID

    END
    GO
```